# Имя поля объекта через переменную

Tags: javascript

Как задать имя поля объекта через переменную?

```
var key = "mykey";
var o = {
    key:"val"
}
```

Данный код создает поле с именем key, а нужно передать имя через переменную.

Comment: А смысл от этого? не проще ли сразу через объект его и создавать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
var key = "mykey";
var o = {
    [key]: "val"
};
console.log(o, o.mykey);
```

[Computed property names (ES2015) - Вычисляемые названия свойств](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)